# .htaccess rewrite replace ?s with &s after formating

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a url like the following: **example.com/respond/admin/94**

I am using the following .htaccess file within the admin folder take the 94, or any id, and replace it with a query string parameter:

```
RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /respond/admin/?alarm=$1 [L]
```

However, more query string parameters can be dynamically added to the URL via JavaScript like such: **example.com/respond/admin/94?parameter=value**

I cannot modify the JavaScript to use &s instead of ?s because it is used globally across our website. It just checks if a question mark is already present, and if so, it uses an ampersand instead. So my question is: **how do I replace one or more ?s with &s while still maintaining the id formatting in my .htaccess file?** I have tried a few examples that I had found to little avail.

I have already referred to the apache mod_rewrite documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add your own query string, but also want to preserve an existing query string, you must use the [`QSA|qsappend`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag

> When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query strings to be combined.

So your rule would become

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /respond/admin/?alarm=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: That part of the .htaccess was actually working without the QSA flag I guess, but how would I go about replacing the question marks with ampersands?

Comment: *Without* QSA, the previous query string will be discarded. *With* QSA, the previous query string will be appended properly. You don't need to replace any question marks.

Comment: Okay, never mind. It wasn't working, but I had forgotten to clear my browser cache. Thanks!

Comment: What does that mean? Is it working now? If it is not, what is the problem?

Comment: The 301 was permanently redirecting. I had to clear my browser cache for the changes to take effect.